# PHP - Extremely light templating system

Tags: php, string, templates, variables

does anyone know a php templating system that is very simple, something like almost as simple as `str_replace("{variable}", $variable);` ?

I need this for a series of textareas in the administration panel, where the site admin should change templates for various elements of the website (not complex stuff like pages etc, just blocks of content)

Comment: if you any only streplace tempalte system, write it, this is few lines.

Comment: yes, but it's not very elegant. at least is there any way to map multiple variables to strings wrapped between { }, to avoid using 1000 str_replace's ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/**
 * Renders a single line. Looks for {{ var }}
 *
 * @param string $string
 * @param array $parameters
 *
 * @return string
 */
function renderString($string, array $parameters)
{
    $replacer = function ($match) use ($parameters)
    {
        return isset($parameters[$match[1]]) ? $parameters[$match[1]] : $match[0];
    };

    return preg_replace_callback('/{{\s*(.+?)\s*}}/', $replacer, $string);
}
```

Comment: Neat. :) It should be said that it's php 5.3+ only, though.

Comment: You'll need to be running PHP 5.3 to use this. Otherwise it is not so elegant.

Comment: Try to avoid this if you can. Regexes are resource-expensive.

Comment: Same as Fabien Potencier's in [Design patterns revisited with PHP 5.3](http://www.slideshare.net/fabpot/design-patternrevisitedphp53) (page 45)

Comment: @Alex You'll need to make a separate function for the callback (outside of the scope you are currently in).

Comment: @efritz figures because Fabien is the author of Symfony2

Answer (score 2):

```
$findReplaces = array(
    'first_name' => $user['first_name'],
    'greeting' => 'Good ' . (date('G') < 12 ) ? 'morning' : 'afternoon'
);

$finds = $replaces = array();

foreach($findReplaces as $find => $replace) {
    $finds[] = '{' . $find . '}';
    $replaces[] = $replace;
}

$content = str_replace($finds, $replaces, $content);
```

Comment: why dont you just include the curly braces, e.g. `{{first_name}}` in the array keys and simply do `str_replace(array_keys($findReplaces),$findReplaces,$content)`

Comment: @Gordon Yep, that is much nicer. The only disadvantage I can see is that the delimiters need to be included which each search term - you know, the whole DRY thing.

Comment: yes, but then again, everyone using a template engine with curly braces over just using PHP deserves that :)

Comment: hehe, I will use that in my next project. no wait, I already do ;)